# Dig till deepest .value or .content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that digs an object till it gets to the last `.value` or `.content` property. I wrote this and for the life of me I cant figure out why it breaks.

```
    var jscGetDeepest = function(obj) {
        try {
            console.info(Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + ' starting jscGetDeepest:', obj, obj.toString());
        } catch(ignore) {}

        while (obj && ('contents' in obj || 'value' in obj)) {
            if ('contents' in obj) {
                obj = obj.contents;
            } else if ('value' in obj) {
                obj = obj.value;
            }
            //console.info('loop jscGetDeepest:', obj.toString());
        }

        if (obj || obj === 0) {
            obj = obj.toString();
        }
        console.info('finaled jscGetDeepest:', obj);
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: How does it break? what doesn't work?

Comment: What does your sample data look like?

Comment: Your `obj = obj.toString()` is likely the culprit.  Why would you do that?

Comment: Thanks all the issue i get is: `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand b`. With `obj.toString()` it hasnt caused problems as it will only cuase issues if it is `undefined` or `null` and i do a check for `if(obj)`

Comment: Sample data can be a number or any object that has deepst value a number or some text. Or an object with no .content or .value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs when inner value in the next iteration is not an object. In this case you get an error message, because `in` operand can't be used with primitives.

To fix it check for object before trying to get deeper. Here is a fixed an slightly improved version with `JSON.stringify` instead of `toString` (maybe better to return object itself without stringifying it?):

```js
var jscGetDeepest = function (obj) {

    while (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && ('contents' in obj || 'value' in obj)) {
        if ('contents' in obj) {
            obj = obj.contents;
        } else if ('value' in obj) {
            obj = obj.value;
        }
    }

    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
    
    return obj;
}

alert( jscGetDeepest({value: {name: 2, contents: {name: 3, value: 23}}}) );
alert( jscGetDeepest({value: {name: 2, value: {name: 3, contents: {name: 4}}}}) );
```

Comment: Thanks a million!! Re: `JSON.stringify` approach too thank you! Would there be a problem with `.toString()` there? Because I mainly use this function to compare two objects deepest `.value`/`.content`. So I do stuff like `if (jscGetDeepest(obj1) == jscGetDeepest(obj2))`, would using `.toString()` be ok? My sincerest thanks!